# ssh-copy-id to remote host

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a question for you! I a made an ssh-key via github.Now i have two machines lets name them local1 and one remote1. from my local1 machine i made `ssh-copy-id remote1t@192.168.x.xxx` and then i ssh to the remote1 host and everything works fine no warnings no nothing! But if i try to ssh from the remote1 to my local1 machine i get something like

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.x.xxx (192.168.x.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is -----------------------------------------.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Shouldn't I be able to connect from the remote1 machine to the local1 machine without this warning? I mean that i have already copied the ssh id Do i have to ssh-copy-id from remote1 to local1 too? thank you for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate keys at play here.

When you use `ssh-copy-id remote`, you are copying the *user* key (identity) as an *authorized_user* on the remote machine.  To use public-key authentication, you will need to ensure that an appropriate *user* public key is stored on each machine to which you wish to `ssh`.

The challenge you are receiving states that you cannot verify the *host* key of the machine `local1` when connecting from `remote1`.  If you answer `yes` at the prompt in your question, you will connect from `remote1` to `local1`, and the publickey of `local1` will be stored on `remote1` so that you do not receive this challenge again.  With default settings, you will receive this warning the first time you connect to any new machine.